# Does this code change the value of each element in the list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Can you explain to me why this code does not change the value of each element in the list?

```
li = [3,4,5]

for elm in li:
    elm = 1
print(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. it changes the value of the `elm` variable. To change the value of the list element you have to use following code.

```
li = [3,4,5]

for i in range(len(li)):
    li[i] = 1
print(li)
```

Comment: yes but in each iteration the value of the elm is 3,4, and 5 right?

Comment: in each iteration value changes to 1. Here I do not iterate over value - I iterate over length of a `li`